# Figuring out why selection is changing (selectionchange)

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, selection, contenteditable

I'm trying to figure out why selection keeps on changing in my React web application. I'm working with contenteditable div and while typing the blinking cursor would occasionally jump to the beginning of the div. I'm only seeing the issue on Android chrome.

I've registered an event handler to catch `selectionchange` events, but by then the call stack doesn't really provide me with much information as to why that event was emitted in the first place. Any tips for debugging what's triggering the selection change?

Comment: Can you add a repo link or code snippets? It could be a few things based on this information.